# Formatting fixed decimal scalar

Tags: perl, printf

I have been experimenting with `sprintf` trying to fix the number of digits to the right of the decimal place as well as to the left.

The following works, but does not handle 0.00 well. As you can see, 0.00 does not align correctly like all the other non-zero decimal values.

`sprintf("%.2f  ", $sw_chgs)`

```
535.14  642.90  20.31  1198.35
442.74  531.90  20.31  994.95
0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

If if I add a field width or designator like %6f to the sprintf, "2f" is printed after the decimal place.

`sprintf("%6f.2f  ", $ws_chgs`

`244.100000.2f`

I want to do something like the following which limits the whole number's field width

`sprintf("%6d  ",   $prev_rd)`

Is that possible with a decimal value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood the format of `printf` formats. It is somewhat like this:

```
"%" <padding>? <minimum width>? "." <precision>? <type>
```

E.g. `%7.2f`. Then this code

```
say join " : ", map sprintf('%7.2f', $_), @$_ for
  [ 535.14, 642.90, 20.31, 1198.35 ],
  [ 442.74, 531.90, 20.31,  994.95 ],
  [   0.00,   0.00,  0.00,    0.00 ],
;
```

prints

```
 535.14 :  642.90 :   20.31 : 1198.35
 442.74 :  531.90 :   20.31 :  994.95
   0.00 :    0.00 :    0.00 :    0.00
```

Note that the min width includes the decimal separator.

The width and precision arguments do not include the type like `f`. Therefore, your `%6f.2f` is parsed as the pattern `%6f`, which precedes the non-special string `.2f`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a note, `6` is number of all chars together in formatted string,

```
 sprintf("%06.2f ", 1);
```

output

```
001.00
```

or without leading zeroes,

```
sprintf("%6.2f ", 1);
```

output

```
  1.00
```

Comment: sprintf("%6.2f ", 1); if no leading zero fill wanted

Comment: @MiguelPrz tnx for comment